# Building with Maven on Jenkins error

Tags: android, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to get an Android application to build on Jenkins however it is failing with an obscure error message. The application builds fine using Maven on my machine, however it doesn't work on Jenkins. Iv'e looked around for a solution and it said update the android SDK which I did however it has not solved the problem. Here is the full stacktrace.

Note:  am referencing the Google Play Servieces and Facebook SDK projects as dependencies.

> ```
> mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty message : Failed to execute goal
> ```
>
> com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:dex
>   (default-dex) on project lv2-geosafe:  cause :  Stack trace : 
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:dex
>   (default-dex) on project lv2-geosafe:     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
>     at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)   at
>   hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)    at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)     at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)   at
>   hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:   at
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase08preparepackage.DexMojo.runDex(DexMojo.java:382)
>     at
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase08preparepackage.DexMojo.execute(DexMojo.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     ... 27 more Caused by:
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001:
>   Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd
>   /root/.hudson/jobs/lv2/workspace/lv2-geosafe &&
>   /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_23/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024M -jar
>   /usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar --dex
>       --output=/root/.hudson/jobs/lv2/workspace/lv2-geosafe/target/classes.dex
>   /root/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.2/gson-2.2.2.jar
>   /root/.m2/repository/com/unboundid/unboundid-ldapsdk/2.3.3/unboundid-ldapsdk-2.3.3.jar
>   /root/.m2/repository/com/terrapages/mapapi/mapapi/1.0.0/mapapi-1.0.0.jar
>   /root/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/google-play-services/2.3.0/google-play-services-2.3.0.jar
>   /root/.hudson/jobs/lv2/workspace/lv2-util/target/lv2-util.jar
>   /root/.m2/repository/com/google/android/support-v4/r7/support-v4-r7.jar
>   /root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
>   /root/.hudson/jobs/lv2/workspace/lv2-model/target/lv2-model.jar
>   /root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.2.0.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar /root/.m2/repository/com/terrapages/ims/model/1.0.7/model-1.0.7.jar
>   /root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.5.6-Final/hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar
>   /root/.m2/repository/com/github/avianey/facebook-android-api/3.0.1/facebook-android-api-3.0.1.jar
>   /root/.m2/repository/ch/acra/acra/4.4.0/acra-4.4.0.jar
>   /root/.m2/repository/com/github/avianey/facebook-android-api/3.0.1/facebook-android-api-3.0.1.apklib
>   /root/.hudson/jobs/lv2/workspace/lv2-api/target/lv2-api-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   /root/.m2/repository/com/terrapages/ims/util/1.0.7/util-1.0.7.jar
>   /root/.hudson/jobs/lv2/workspace/lv2-geosafe/target/classes
>   /root/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/google-play-services/2.3.0/google-play-services-2.3.0.apklib
>   /root/.m2/repository/com/terrapages/ims/api/1.0.7/api-1.0.7.jar,
>   Result = 1    at
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$DefaultCommandExecutor.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:246)
>     at
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase08preparepackage.DexMojo.runDex(DexMojo.java:378)
>     ... 30 more channel stopped Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

Well, digging into your stacktrace you see this line:

Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd /root/.hudson/jobs/lv2/workspace/lv2-geosafe && /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_23/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024M -jar /usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar --dex --output=/root/.hudson/jobs/lv2/workspace/lv2-geosafe/target/classes.dex ... lots of jars ... , Result = 1

If you execute the stated command (including the list if jar files that I left out above, but not including the ", Result = 1") in the terminal you will probably receive more info on why this command is failing. Maybe you don't have and Android SDK at /usr/local/android-sdk?